# How to use OOP to branch from a point class into lines and triangles (Java)

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to create simple objects, branching out from a single point object, into a line object (two points), and then into a triangle object (three points). I understood how to create the point class, though when trying to branch into the line class, I got a bit confused with how to actually go into writing a line class or triangle class using the initial point class. I need some help with going from a single point class into

I can post some code that I have done so far.

I also have read that there are already java geometry classes out there, but I want to actually create these classes to practice with OOP.

edit --- Added code below

```
class Point 
{
private double x;
private double y;

public Point() 
{
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
}

public Point(double x, double y) 
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public double getX() 
{
    return this.x;
}

public double getY() 
{
    return this.y;
}

public void setX(double x) 
{
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(double y) 
{
    this.y = y;
}

public double distance(Point p) 
{
    return Math.sqrt((this.x - p.x) * (this.x - p.x) + (this.y - p.y)
            * (this.y - p.y));
}

public String toString() 
{
    String s = "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    return s;
}

public boolean equals(Point p) 
{
    double delta = 1.0e-18;
    return (Math.abs(this.x - p.x) < delta)
            && (Math.abs(this.y - p.y) < delta);
}

//-----------------Line Class--------------------//
class Line 
{
private Point p1;
private Point p2;

public Line() 
{
    p1 = new Point (0,0);
    p2 = new Point (1,1);
}

public Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) 
{
    p1 = new Point (x1, y1);
    p2 = new Point (x2, y2);
}

public Line(Point p, Point q)
{
    p1 = new Point(p.getX(), p.getY());
    p2 = new Point(q.getX(), q.getY());
}

public Point getP1()
{
    return this.p1;
}

public Point getP2()
{
    return this.p2;
}

public void setP1(double x, double y)
{
    Point p1 = new Point(x, y);
    this.p1 = p1;
}

public void setP2(double x, double y)
{
    Point p2 = new Point(x, y);
    this.p2 = p2;   
}

public boolean isParallelY() 
{
    double delta = 1.0e-18;
    return (Math.abs(p1.getX() - p2.getX()) < delta);
}

public boolean isParallelX()
{
    double delta = 1.0e-18;
    return (Math.abs(p1.getY() - p2.getY()) < delta);
}

public boolean isParallel (Line line)
{
    if (this.Slope() == line.Slope())
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

public double Slope() 
{
    double inf = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    if(isParallelY())
        return inf;
    return ((p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p2.getX() - p1.getX()));
}

public double xIntercept()
{
    return -(p1.getY() / Slope() - p1.getX());
}

public double yIntercept()
{
    return p1.getY() - (Slope() * p1.getX());
}
```

I am still adding methods to the line class right now and have not started on the triangle class (though I was thinking of creating a triangle with 3 points rather than 3 lines. And sorry about the branching confusion, I am relatively new.

Comment: Can we see what you have so far, so your question doesn't get deleted?

Comment: A line is a new class, it describes a line. A line is described with 2 points one at each end. So a line class will have to points and the code to draw the line (if they are drawing classes).

Comment: What is all the talk about branching? I was thinking it was just a way of talking/writing. However you have also tagged the post with branching. Branching is not an OOP concept.

Comment: so what's your question? be specific on your question please.

Answer (score 2):

A `Line` has 2 `Points`, so any `Line` class will have 2 `Point-attributes`

Any `Triangle` has 3 `Points`, so any `Triangle` class will have 3 `Point-attributes`

You can create the constructor of these classes to ensure correct objects.

```
public Line(Point point1, Point point2)
{
    this.point1 = point1;
    this.point2 = point2;
}
```

and for the `Triangle` class

```
public Triangle(Line line1, Line line2, Line line3)
{
    this.point1 = line1.firstpoint();
    this.point2 = line2.firstpoint();
    this.point3 = line3.firstpoint();
}
```

or

```
public Triangle(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3)
{
    this.point1 = point1;
    this.point2 = point2;
    this.point3 = point3;
}
```

Since each class contains the right attributes you can calculate with them.

Comment: Frankly, I'd rather use three points to define a triangle rather than three lines. Lines can be created from two of the points if needed. In your line-based triangle, you'd better check that line 2's first point is the same as line 1's second point, etc. The second one doesn't have this complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do OOP, think about what objects exist in your domain, and what messages they understand - that's all [Mr Kay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay) ever talked about :)

In your case, you've found `Point`s. Seems you are thinking in a 2D point, and that's why you've just used `x` and `y` coordinates. In a 2D world, what would we like to ask to a `Point`? It's position/coordinates, right - we already have them. What else? A distance to another `Point`, right. That seems to be pretty much everything a `Point` can do by now.

Wait - we can ask it to join another `Point`, creating a `Line`. So, maybe, doing `aPoint.lineTo(anotherPoint)` isn't that bad. But, hey, the important thing is we are actually creating `Line`s.

They consist in a pair of dots. What would we like to ask to a `Line`? It's lenght, of course. It's clearly the same as the distance between its points. We can ask it the distance to a `Point` (some mathematicians [already defined it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line), yeah). We can ask a Line if it's parallel with another one, or if they cross. We can ask it at which point they cross. We can ask the angle formed by two lines. And, then, again, we can ask it to join with a third point, to create a `Triangle`.

Then we'll have a convex shape, so new fun things as area, perimeter, internal angles, external angles.

Try to think of things, concepts and definitions, and implement them as simply as you can. Try to make code as nearly as possible to the colloquial definitions of the concepts it represents. And construct new abstractions based on the previous ones.

Besides all of this, there's one thing you shall not forget: programming is modeling. Models are abstractions. OOP is about using objects to model the portion of the reality we are interested in. If you don't define the scope of what things you wish to model (as this case is just an educational activity, with no real requirements), you can spend your hole life adding methods to your objects, without much sense. Think in advance what things you would like to be able to do with your Points, Lines, Triangles, etc, and limit yourself to them.

Happy hacking :)